# Is there a way to write a method with generic/dynamic return type?

Tags: java, generics, return-type

It is just a curious question.

Code:

```
ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add(5);
al.add(5.5);
al.add("abcd");

int    a = get(0);
double b = get(1);
String c = get(2);
```

I know the index of data type like `0` index has `int`.

I know about casting like

```
int a = (int) list.get(0);
```

But how can we write a method `get(int index)` which can return any data type and directly assign to a variable?

Thank you!

Comment: No, you can't.  Instead of having a `List` with objects of different classes, have a class with fields of different classes.  Mixing types like this is usually a significant code smell.

Comment: The people who have to maintain your code will come to your house with evil intent -- actually they'll probably just rewrite the code correctly and curse your name under their breath.

Comment: @JimGarrison It is just a curious question which I have stated in the beginning of the question 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do it, but I'm not sure this would be a recommended way of programming:

```
  public static <T> T get (List<?> list, int index) {
    return (T) list.get (index);
  }
```

Comment: But how does `T` gets the type?

Comment: @psh Google "type inference".

Answer (score -1):

What you wish to do is something like this:

```
//TypelessList is a user-created class with custom casting methods
List typeLess = new TypelessList();
int a = list.getInt(0);
double b = list.getDouble(1);
String c = list.getString(2);
```

However, that is not recommended, as it and defeats the purpose of the generics you are using. Casting is also a slow operation. 
What you should be doing is making lists that are more specific, like this:

```
List<Integer> wrappedInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
wrappedInts.add(Integer.valueOf(5));
int a = wrappedInts.get(0).intValue();
```

This way, excessive casting is unnecessary.

The **Integer** class is used because primitive types cannot be used in Lists. *Reference unboxing for more details.*

Answer (score -1):

Use `instanceof` to determine the class.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main
{
    static LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        list.push("String");
        list.push(2);
        list.push(new Date());

        for(Object obj: list)
        {
            if(obj instanceof String)
                System.out.println("String: " + obj);
            else if(obj instanceof Integer)
                System.out.println("int: " + obj);
            else if(obj instanceof Date)
                System.out.println("Date: " + obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it fails if there is inheritance.

Comment: This is a poor solution even if it does what they want.